# Search in 2010: Finding items of a certain content type or one of it's descendants

Tags: 2010, search

I want to use a fixed query in a `CoreResultWebPart` to find all items of a certain content type or one of it's descendants via search.

I tried to create Managed Properties, mapping Crawled Properties like `ContentType`, `ows_ContentType`, `ContentTypeId` ...

The only thing I managed to do was searching by the content type name, but this won't get me the descendants ... I tried to search with expressions like `ContentTypeId:0xsomeid`, `ContentTypeId:0xsomeid*` or `ContentTypeId:'0xsomeid*'` ... but to no avail.

Comment: ContentTypeId:0xSomeId* should work. Can you tell me what results are coming back in the ContentTypeId managed property?

Comment: It is returned empty for all elements ... that explains, why the search filter doesn't work, but I don't find any other crawled properties, I could add to the mapping ...

Comment: You have to resolve that first. Once you have it let us know if this is still a problem.

Comment: When I inspect the managed property ContentType, I see that it is mapped to "Basic:5" and "ows_ContentType" ... is there some "Basic:#" property, that I have to map my ContentTypeId managed property to?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott does i.e. ContentTypeId:0x0105* work on your farm? If yes, can you tell me, how your managed property is configured?

Comment: I checked the ContentTypeId managed property I created against more items now. It is only filled, if the found item is an document. 0x01* finds only documents, 0x0101* of course too, 0x0108* finds no items at all.

Comment: Are you certain of your Content Type ID? Are you sure your content is being crawled?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are looking for Tasks and Links. In my environment if I search for `ContentType:Task` I get all tasks (0x0108...) (that I have access to). Likewise, if I search for `ContentType:Link` I get all links (0x0105...). Also, If I search for `ContentTypeId:0x0108*` I get the same Task results.

My environment is an out of the box configuration for ContentType and ContentTypeId. Both are Text, Query, Retrieve and Safe.

- **ContentType** is mapped to *Basic5, ows_ContentType*
- **ContentTypeId** is mapped to *ows_ContentTypeId*

Comment: I'm not searching for tasks or links, I used them as example, because they exist on your farm as well. As I said ContentType:TypeName works for me, but I need ContentTypeId to search for elements of my custom ContentType and it's descendants.

I don't have a crawled property ows_ContentTypeId ...

Do you use SP 2010 or 2013?

Comment: On 2013. I can test it on 2010 tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, my problem is on 2010 ... now I'm really curious, if you can reproduce the behaviour tomorrow :)

Comment: Busy weekend, not done testing, initial tests echo your findings, documents and some list items have a ContentTypeId but not all. I need a little more time with it.